# R keeps creating 3 variable plots despite only being provided 2 variables

Tags: r

I'm new to R.

I am having trouble creating a plot from a CSV file.

My issue is that R Studio keeps creating 3 variable plots despite only being fed 2 variables and I don't really know what exactly I'm doing wrong.

```
data <- read.csv("Dados.csv", TRUE, ";")
rendimento = data$Rendimento.mensal.em.euros
despesa = data$Despesas.mensais.em.euros
plot(rendimento, despesa)
```

The values provided are the following

[image: Values]

But the plot created has an extra variable

[image: Plot[2]]

I want to create a simple plot so I can calculate the Regression line, but R keeps creating barplots instead of regular plots due to the extra variable.

Comment: Try converting to numeric first: `rendimento = as.numeric(data$Rendimento.mensal.em.euros)` (same with the other one). The issue is probably because you're plotting factors.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.

Comment: Just to add that the last line of the output gives it away: *100 Levels etc*. Another way is to inspect your data with `str(data)` or `str(rendimento)`. I suggest that you always do this before further processing.

Comment: What are those 100 levels supposed to mean? I assumed it meant that I had 100 values in my table.

Comment: Those 100 levels mean you have a factor object. Try `is(data$Rendimento.mensal.em.euros)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert the values to numeric such as

```
despesa = as.numeric(data$Despesas.mensais.em.euros)
```

Thanks to the user mickey for providing the answer